# How to give focus to an iFrame in firefox just page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

How to give focus to an iFrame in firefox just page is loaded?

FYI: I tried focus() javascript & jQuery functions to do this, works properly for XP, but doesn't work for Windows 7?
Also, how does foucs() functionality differs from platform to another one?

Answer (score 1):

try to [trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) the [focus](http://api.jquery.com/focus/) or [focusin](http://api.jquery.com/focusin/) event on page/dom ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('iframe').trigger('focusin');
});
```

Comment: The focusin event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, gains focus.
What I need to give focus to iFrame, while page is loaded.